# Get form dropdown value before POST?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page with 2 forms.   The first form (below) is just a drop down list of values which controls what is loaded into the 2nd form.   The 1st form submits to the same page.

Without making the 1st form (on submit) open a 2nd page with the 2nd form, is there a way (on load) to get the currently selected value of the drop down for use in the second form?    This is only a problem on the initial page load.  Thanks.

```
<form action="/get_gs_link_status.php" method="post" onchange="submitForm()">
    <select name="select_PM" id="select_PM">
    <?php
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<option value=\"{$row['PM']}\">";
            echo $row['PM'];
            echo "</option>";
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</form>

        <p id="PID_value"></p>
        <script>
        function submitForm() {
            var x = document.getElementById("select_PM").value;
            document.getElementById("PID_value").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What does "without making the 1st form" mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase It's not "making the 1st form", it's "making [it] open a 2nd page".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `onload` handler that calls `submitForm()`.

```
    <p id="PID_value"></p>
    <script>
    function submitForm() {
        var x = document.getElementById("select_PM").value;
        document.getElementById("PID_value").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", submitForm);
    </script>
```